# How can I avoid blocking popup windows?

Tags: flutter, browser, flutter-web

If I run the below code in *iOS* or *Android* apps, then after `5 seconds` the browser will launch and call the specified site. But a new tab will not be created on the *Web* version, since it will be blocked by the browser as a popup window.

Is there a way to get around this blockage?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.light(),
    home: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => launch('https://flutter.dev', forceSafariVC: false)),
        child: Text('Tap'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it will be blocked" ? I've just tested your code in Chrome and it opened correctly the website in a new tab.

Comment: A modern browser usually blocks popup windows caused by indirect user action. From my practice, Safari starts blocking after 1 second, and Chrome after 5. Thus, if you put 10 seconds, the pop-up will block, unless of course, you have disabled pop-up blocking in your browser.